# Ubuntu 18.04 auto updates

Tags: 18.04, grub2, updates

Ive just let Ubuntu run its auto software-update (which I have always done) and it bust GRUB, again (2nd time), and I had to use Boot-Repair again, is there any thing I can do to stop the auto updates from damaging GRUB?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu Desktop, you can  turn off auto-update via Ubuntu Software Center. Open Ubuntu Software Center, and go to Edit --> Software Sources. Choose "Never" for "Automatically check for updates".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm aware of this feature, but I would prefer to keep the auto updates on. I'm not sure what it does to GRUB on an update as (I thought) GRUB2 is up to date.